# Align elements in a row and horizontally centered in their column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a grid with some icons and their respective id.

For example, I have this code using bootstrap:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row flex">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    <p class="text-center channel-number">2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    <p class="text-center channel-number">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    <p class="text-center channel-number">11</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

now the number will just stay right under the image, but I want the number to be horizontally align with the other numbers and centered below the image.

How can I do this?

Using flex or does bootstrap has a way of doing this?

Thanks!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8mm1p03/1/)

Comment: Seems like one of the simplest options would be to separate them into two rows: https://jsfiddle.net/b8mm1p03/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML** (no changes)

**CSS**

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.flex > .col-md-2 {
  display: flex;                   /* create nested flex container */
  flex-direction: column;          /* stack children (image and number) vertically */
}

img { margin: auto;}               /* forces numbers to bottom edge of container */
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b8mm1p03/6/)

Learn more about `justify-content` and `auto` margins here:

- [**Methods for Aligning Flex Items**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)